# Migrate passwords from Drupal 7 to Django

Tags: django, drupal, cryptography, passwords, sha

I am migrating a site from Drupal 7 to Django 1.4, including the current users. How can I work with the passwords that were hashed by Drupal?

According to [this](http://joncave.co.uk/2011/01/password-storage-in-drupal-and-wordpress/), Drupal 7 hashes passwords using SHA-512 (they are stored in the form of a string starting with "$S$").

Django 1.4 now contains a number of [options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) for storing passwords, with a default of SHA-256, but I can't find an option for SHA-512. While [this app](https://github.com/fwenzel/django-sha2) appears to allow the use of SHA2 algorithms, I'm not sure it's compatible with Django 1.4 (as 1.4 has a flexible password hasher).

What is the simplest way to do this?

ETA: I've built a password hasher that mimics Drupal's algorithm and makes migration easy. Since I've already accepted an answer, I won't unaccept, but for anyone who wants to do Drupal to Django migration in the future, the code is stored on [Django snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2729/#c4520) and as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/2344345/8713ee2d498ef9d0263a53e4c367aa3507a57d81).

Comment: I'm trying to migrate users from a Drupal 7 app into a Django 1.8 app that uses Stormpath. (As per http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176008/getting-password-hashes-and-salts-from-drupal-7 ). What I'm stuck on is how to get the password hashes and salts out of the Drupal app. Could you please help with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Drupal very well, but I suppose that the passwords are stored hashed. If that's the case, you'll have to copy the passwords (I mean, copy them unchanged) and you'll have to change the way Django hashes its passwords, using the exactly same way of Drupal, with the same Security Salt.

I really don't know how to do that, but the logic for passwords is contained in the User object. For example. the `User.set_password()` function (described [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L293)) uses the [make_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L51) function.

I think with a little research you'll find the way to change it, but the important thing is, remember that the functions must be equals! ie:

drupal_hash(x) == django_hash(x) for every x in the allowed passwords set.

**EDIT:**

Taking a deeper look django get the has function with the [get_hasher](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L94) function. Now in the 1.4 version there's a way to specify how Django will select that function. Take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-django-stores-passwords

Finally, in order to create your own function, you can take a look at how it's done on the [MD5PasswordHasher](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L304). It seems really simple. You can use the [hashlib python library](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) to generate sha-512 algorithms.

Changing the encode method would require somthing similar to:

```
def encode(self, password, salt):
    assert password
    assert salt and '$' not in salt
    hash = hashlib.sha512(salt + password).hexdigest()
    return "%s$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, salt, hash)
```

Comment: That's precisely the problem I'm having: I haven't found a way to use SHA-512 hashing in Django, which appears to be Drupal 7's hashing method

Comment: It does! But as @Alasdiar says, I'm not sure how to extract the salt from the stored password...

Comment: If anyone tries in the future: the salt is the 5th character through the 12th in the stored Drupal string

Comment: Solved it! Code is posted in my question above (normally I'd answer my own question and accept, but I don't like to unaccept an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, David Robinson, for your code.  That made my day!  It seems to have a flaw, though:  If Drupal decided to not use 'C' but 'D' for the number of iterations, it fails.  I fixed the class definition slightly:

```
class DrupalPasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
    algorithm = "S"
    iter_code = 'C'
    salt_length = 8

    def encode(self, password, salt, iter_code=None):
        """The Drupal 7 method of encoding passwords"""
        if iter_code == None:
            iterations = 2 ** _ITOA64.index(self.iter_code)
        else:
            iterations = 2 ** _ITOA64.index(iter_code)
        hash = hashlib.sha512(salt + password).digest()

        for i in range(iterations):
            hash = hashlib.sha512(hash + password).digest()

        l = len(hash)

        output = ''
        i = 0

        while i < l:
            value = ord(hash[i])
            i = i + 1

            output += _ITOA64[value & 0x3f]
            if i < l:
                value |= ord(hash[i]) << 8

            output += _ITOA64[(value >> 6) & 0x3f]
            if i >= l:
                break
            i += 1

            if i < l:
                value |= ord(hash[i]) << 16

            output += _ITOA64[(value >> 12) & 0x3f]
            if i >= l:
                break
            i += 1

            output += _ITOA64[(value >> 18) & 0x3f]

        longhashed = "%s$%s%s%s" % (self.algorithm, iter_code,
                                    salt, output)
        return longhashed[:54]

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        hash = encoded.split("$")[1]
        iter_code = hash[0]
        salt = hash[1:1 + self.salt_length]
        return encoded == self.encode(password, salt, iter_code)
```

Comment: Glad this could help, Karsten! I think I'm confused about how your code differs: wasn't this handled by the original line `iterations = 2 ** _ITOA64.index(hash[0])`? BTW, I'm maintaining the code now as a GitHub gist, see answer for details. (I edited it to your version for now).

Comment: (For comparison, [here](https://gist.github.com/2344345/2f9f79fccef285ff4282ac640cf8cfb56fb069fd) is the original code)

Comment: Revisiting this, I tend to agree.  May be it was just a readability-issue that confused me, with `iterations` being 'C' and `2 ** _ITOA64.index('C')` at the same time, and then I resolved that by making `iter_code` effectively a key character, and `iterations` the power of two integer.  Now I see that I could have achieved that with fewer lines of code changes.
Anyway, great piece of code, thanks for your help!

Comment: Will you please explain how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an update to David's excellent answer for python 3, since hashlib no longer accepts strings. Also, this includes support for the odd "U$S$*" hashes, which apparently are from an update and I found a bunch of them in my drupal database.

https://gist.github.com/skulegirl/bec420b5272b87d9e4dbd39e947062fc

And as a bonus, here's the code that I used to import my xml file of user data in. (I just created the xml file via an sql export after doing a query on the users table.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

tree = ET.parse('/PATH/TO/Users.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for row in root:
    user_dict = {}
    for field in row:
        user_dict[field.attrib['name']] = field.text
    user = User.objects.create_user(user_dict['name'], user_dict['mail'])
    if user_dict['pass'][0] == '$':
        user_dict['pass'] = user_dict['pass'][1:]
    user.password = user_dict['pass']
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement this by creating your own subclass of `BasePasswordHasher`, and adding it to your `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting.

Python's hashlib implements sha512.

The [page David linked to in the question](http://joncave.co.uk/2011/01/password-storage-in-drupal-and-wordpress/) explains how the number of iterations (16385 for Drupal 7) is encoded in the hash, but it's not clear to me how to get the salt.

*Edit*: In the comment to @santiago's answer, David says the "the salt is the 5th character through the 12th in the stored Drupal string".

Comment: the salt in drupal is stored in the settings.php file.

Comment: Nice one David. Thanks for posting your solution.