# How to use password hasher snippet in Django?

Tags: django, drupal, password-hash

I am trying to move Druap 7 site to django 1.7 without invalidating user passwords, and this proved to be daunting.

Fortunately, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876700/migrate-passwords-from-drupal-7-to-django) SO question and [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3030/) hashing snippet but there is no documentation and as a newbie to django, I have no clue how to integrate the snippet into my project.

So greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PASSWORD_HASHERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS)

Django uses first entry in that list to store password and all the other entries are valid hashers that can be used to check `existing` `passwords`.

*settings.py.*

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'myproject.myapp.drupal_hasher.DrupalPasswordHasher', # Check this out
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint Raja. I added 'myproject.myapp.DrupalPasswordHasher' to the settings, and I copied the DrupalPasswordHasher.py snippet into myproject.myapp folder but I get this error:  ImportError at /accounts/login/
Module "myapp.DrupalPasswordHasher" does not define a "DrupalPasswordHasher" attribute/class. Any ideas?

Comment: @supermario just use `myapp.drupal_hasher.DrupalPasswordHasher` where `drupal_hasher.py` located in `myapp` ... Let me know ...!

Comment: sorry, I corrected the path, but now when I test an imported user with a known password, django refuses to authenticate him. How should I test whether the snippet create correct password hash?

Comment: @supermario So the import is working ...! Initial problem is resolved ah ?. Now you are asking another question ? What is the error you are getting when authenticate ?

Comment: @supermario can you come to chat after 30 mins ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69376/discussion-between-raja-and-supermario).

Comment: Sorry, I missed you. Please refer the the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095828/customized-authentication-method-does-not-work-in-django